# Introduce delay between calling a set of methods in java

Tags: java

I have a specific use case where I have 10 methods I need test by calling them continuously for about 5 minutes. To avoid the loading the backend handling these calls, I plan on having a one second delay between each method call.

My code looks like something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // start i at 1 for initial delay
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run()
            {
                callMethodA();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                callMethodB();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                callMethodC();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                callMethodD();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                callMethodE();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                callMethodF();
            }
        }, 30000 * i); // 5 second intervals
    }
}
```

I wanted to know if there's a better way to introduce the delay rather than using Thread.sleep() after every method call. I wasn't sure if the ScheduledExecutorService can be used for this purpose?

Comment: suppose Quartz Scheduler can be used in this issue also. [this](https://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/) is a good example to get you started.

Comment: I like the Thread.sleep approach better since there's really no concurrency that needs to happen. But I would put the methods into a list and sleep between iterations when looping through the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a specific use case where I have 10 methods I need test by calling them continuously for about 5 minutes. To avoid the loading the backend handling these calls, I plan on having a one second delay between each method call.

For this purpose, I don't see the need for scheduling. You can simply loop `n` times and call the methods with some sleep in between:

```
Runnable[] calls = {
        () -> callMethodA(),
        () -> callMethodB(),
        // ...
};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (Runnable runnable : calls) {
        runnable.run();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the precision you are looking for.

For all practical purposes, sleep is fine. It's quite literally putting the thread to sleep for some amount of time and the process is doing other stuff in the meantime.

A more robust approach to task scheduling in general is a `ScheduledExecutorService`, so you might want to consider that instead.

However, what is not very nice about your code is that you are basically enumerating the method calls. Consider using multiple schedulers with some offset (i.e. start them at different times such that the tasks do not overlap such that you don't need to sleep inside the task).